# Grammar for parsing simple mathematical expression

Tags: formal-grammars

mexp ::= (< mexp >) | < mexp >< mathlowop >< mexp > | < mulexp > | < float > | < var >

mulexp ::= < mexp >< mathhighop >< mexp >

mathlowop ::= + | -

mathhighop ::= / | *

That's the BNF I've come up with for parsing simple mathematical expressions where the operands can only be floats or variables. I've looked at a number of resources in books and on the web and for the same type of problem, they usually have a slightly longer, more complex bnf. Is my BNF incorrect in some way? Or is it correct but there is a significant advantage in doing it another way?

Comment: It would help if you could give a particular grammar whose differences you don't get. As it is, it's impossible to give you a good answer; one can imagine many features a grammar might have. (Also, [see here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3053/arithmetic-expressions-grammar-transformation?rq=1) for a related question.)

Comment: Here [Unambiguous grammar for exponentiation operation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17170820/1673391) explain a similar grammar, also explained how can you correctly convert it into unambiguous/ambiguous form.

Comment: What have you done to try to validate your grammar?  Can you frame a more general question that is more likely to be useful to others?  The purpose of this site is to build up an archive of high-quality questions and answers that will likely be useful to others.  Right now, this question is very specific and unlikely to be helpful to others.  We are not a place to outsource debugging or testing tasks.  And, questions where a possible answer is "yes, it's correct" tend not to be a good fit for our format.

Answer (score 7):

Your grammar will generate mathematical expressions, but you haven't captured the notion of operator precedence. For instance, there are two different ways your grammar can generate the expression $a+a*a$, one having the interpretation we'd write as $a+[a*a]$ and the other having $[a+a]*a$. Using the jargon, we'd say your grammar is ambiguous.

A grammar that avoids this problem is

< expression > ::= < term > + < expression > | < term > - < expression > | < term >

< term > ::= < factor > * < term > | < factor > / < term > | < factor >

< factor > ::= (< expression >) | < float > | < var >

See if you can generate $a+a*a$ in two different ways using your grammar and then try the same thing with this grammar. That should give you an idea of what's going on here.

Comment: Do note that this grammar does not handle the unary minus

Comment: How could it be done to handle it too? would this work? `< term > ::= < factor > * < term > | < factor > / < term > | - < factor > | < factor >`

Comment: If you apply that in `<term>` then you'll be accepting expressions of the form `a + - b`, the unary minus should be included in the definition of `<expression>`

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a grammar, then yours is correct. If you are going to implement a parser, you might want to tweak your grammar a bit. It depends on the tools you are going to use.